specify different required python version for users vs. contributors
When building the following pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = [ "poetry-core",]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "sigfig"
version = "1.3.6"
description = "Python library for rounding numbers (with expected results)"
authors = [ "Michael Busuttil <mike.busuttil@gmail.com>", "Travis Valdez <valdezt@gmail.com>",]
maintainers = [ "Michael Busuttil <mike.busuttil@gmail.com>",]
readme = "README.rst"
license = "MIT License"
keywords = [ "round", "rounding", "significant figures", "significant digits", "sigfigs", "sigdigs", "decimals", "uncertainty", "uncertainties", "numeric", "numerical", "number", "numbers", "data", "format", "style", "publication",]
classifiers = [ "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable", "Intended Audience :: Developers", "Intended Audience :: Education", "Intended Audience :: Financial and Insurance Industry", "Intended Audience :: Healthcare Industry", "Intended Audience :: Other Audience", "Intended Audience :: Manufacturing", "Intended Audience :: Science/Research", "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11", "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.12", "Operating System :: OS Independent", "Topic :: Education", "Topic :: Education :: Computer Aided Instruction (CAI)", "Topic :: Office/Business :: Financial", "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering", "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Information Analysis", "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics", "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Physics", "Topic :: Software Development", "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries", "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules", "Topic :: Utilities",]

[tool.poetry.urls]
Homepage = "https://sigfig.readthedocs.io/"
Documentation = "https://sigfig.readthedocs.io/"
Repository = "https://github.com/drakegroup/sigfig.git"
Issues = "https://github.com/drakegroup/sigfig/issues"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
sortedcontainers = "^2.4.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
semver = "^3.0.2"
pyyaml = "^6.0.1"
requests = "^2.31.0"
toml = "^0.10.2"
numpy = "^1.26.2"
coverage = "^7.3.2"
click = "^8.1.7"
coverage-badge = "^1.1.2"
sphinx = "^8.1.3"
sphinx-rtd-theme = "^3.0.1"
twine = "^5.1.1"
build = "^1.2.2.post1"

with
poetry run python -m build

the package info metadata states that the required Python version is >=3.11 as you would expect.
$ tar xfO dist/sigfig-1.3.6.tar.gz sigfig-1.3.6/PKG-INFO | grep Requires-Python
Requires-Python: >=3.11,<4.0

However, the sigfig package still works for those using a Python version as low as 3.6 when pip allows it.  Python 3.11 is meant only to be a dev dependency, not a usage/core dependency.
In order to convey this in the PKG-INFO metadata I tried putting requires-python = ">= 3.6" in the [tool.poetry] section
[tool.poetry]
requires-python = ">= 3.6"

which fails when building.
$ poetry run python -m build

The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - Additional properties are not allowed ('requires-python' was unexpected)

I also tried specifying the different Python versions in the [tool.poetry.dependencies] and [tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies] sections
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

but then poetry fails to work properly
$ poetry lock
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.6s)

The current project's Python requirement (>=3.6,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - build requires Python >=3.8, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.6,<3.8

Is anyone aware of a way to tell pip that any user with Python >=3.6 is able to use this package?

A somewhat hacky approach to achieve the desired result is the following:

set python = "^3.6" in the [tool.poetry.dependencies] section of pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"


build and publish to PyPI

$ poetry run python -m build
$ poetry run twine upload dist/*


roll-back the python version in the [tool.poetry.dependencies] section of pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

